# jQuery show, get element by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, anchor, show

I'm creating a news page. I need to find out if there is set an anchor to an article. If not, I just show the latest article. An example URL with anchor is: **example.com/news.php#article43**

The HTML structure is:

```
<div>
  <a name="article43"></a>
  <h2>TITLE</h2>
  <div class="news_content"></div>
</div>
```

And my JS is this:

```
 var anchor = $(location).attr('href').split('#');
        if(anchor[1]){
            $('a[name=' + anchor[1] + ']').next('.news_content').show();
        }else{
            $('.news_content').first().show();
        }
```

Something doesn't work.

Comment: Use `location.hash` instead.

Comment: @VisioN True, but it still works with the way above

Comment: I thought the location.hash doesn't work for older browsers. Isn't this true?

Comment: @Shmiddty No you don't. That's only if the `value` contains special characters that jQuery string parsing uses...such as `[` and several others. It's not required, but encouraged, and needed with special characters

Comment: @Ian you seem to understand this. And you are sure my code should work? That's mad.

Comment: `.next('.news_content')` will always return an empty collection since it doesn't immediately follow the anchor tag. You probably want `.nextAll('.news_content')` or `.siblings('.news_content')` with the form likely being more performant.

Comment: @SoBiT Your code should be fine. Other than what Shmiddty pointed out

Comment: And how can I change this? Because that's exactly what happens. not even the first().show() works. The HTML structure you can see in my question

Comment: @SoBiT So you're sure the code is getting into the correct block of the `if/else`? You could do this inside of the `if(anchor[1])` block: `var target = $('a[name=' + anchor[1] + ']'); alert(target.length); target.nextAll('.news_content').first().show();`

Comment: Consider adding a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) instead of downvoting everyone who wants to help despite incomplete context.

Comment: @SoBiT This will alert the number of matched elements. If it says 0, then that means no element matches with that name. By the way, where is this code being executed? Is it inside of `$(document).ready` or similar method? Or out in the open? Or in an event?

Comment: @SoBiT And are you sure that some parent of the target `.news_content` isn't hidden? Showing a child inside of a hidden parent won't actually show the child on the page. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Ian First, yes I use this in $(document).ready and no, the news_content elements are the only hidden.

Comment: @SoBiT Did you try alerting the length of the matched elements inside of the `if` block like I suggested? Like: `var target = $('a[name=' + anchor[1] + ']'); alert(target.length); target.nextAll('.news_content').first().show();` That way you can see if, for some reason, the element isn't being matched correctly

Comment: @Ian I just tried this. It alerts 1. And it also shows the correct one. I'll try to complete the code with this now

Comment: @Ian This is mad. I just removed the alert and it doesn't work anymore ôO

Comment: @SoBiT haha crazy. glad you got it working though

Comment: This discussion is growing too long and hard to follow. However it contains good information which should be integrated into the the question or an answer. Please do that and if needed, continue the discussion in the chat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` will only return the **immediate** sibling after the element, you probably want `nextAll`:

```
$('a[name=' + anchor[1] + ']').nextAll('.news_content').show();
```

or, if your HTML structure doesn't involve wrapping, ie:

```
<div>
  <a name="article43"></a>
  <h2>TITLE</h2>
  <div class="news_content"></a>
  <a name="article44"></a>
  <h2>TITLE</h2>
  <div class="news_content"></a>
</div>
```

You'd want: http://jsfiddle.net/AVg3y/

```
$('a[name=' + anchor[1] + ']').nextAll('.news_content').first().show();
```

Also, this is probably just a typo, but your HTML is malformed. It should be:

```
<div>
      <a name="article43"></a>
      <h2>TITLE</h2>
      <div class="news_content"></div> //<-- oops
</div>
```

Comment: Check the demo I just updated the answer with. Does this resemble your structure?

Comment: It was part of my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this (use siblings instead of next):

```
var anchor = location.href.split('#');

if(anchor[1]) {
    $('a[name=' + anchor[1] + ']').siblings('.news_content').show();
} else {
    $('.news_content').first().show();
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is an approach without using location.hash demanded.

Comment: Well that's exactly the same things as I have. If I alert() my anchor[1] it has the correct value.

Comment: Updated my anwser: According to you HTML structure you have to use siblings instead of next, because the content is not the direct neighbor of the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hash by looking at `window.location.hash`.  Use `substring(1)`, to return everything after the `#` in the `window.location.hash` value.

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    $('a[name=' + window.location.hash.substring(1) + ']').next('.news_content').show();
} else {
    $('.news_content').first().show();
}
```

Comment: @Ian I agree need to validate hash but can never have hash without it haveing `#` as in your fiddle

Comment: @charlietfl All my point is that the original code should work fine. It doesn't **need** to use `window.location.hash`...I would suggest using it as well...but it's not the solution. The fiddle shows that you can still get the hash with jQuery like the OP has, with `$(location).attr('href').split('#')`

Comment: @MikeBrant Your solution implies the problem lies with how to get the hash value. Your code is no different from the OP, logically. You just use a different method of getting the hash value.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

First: I ned to use nextAll() as many of you said.

Second: I included a CSS with jQuery (one that's only used when JS is enabled). I had to include this before the $(document).ready function. Else it was setting the news_content elements to display:none

Thanks to all who tried to help me.

Answer (score -1):

All the answers have simlilar variations for hash, but none check to see if the hash has a matching element:

I suggest checking that the element exists as part of condition.

```
var contentToDisplay=$('.news_content').first();
if(anchor[1]){
   var $link=  $('a[name="' + anchor[1] + '"]');
   contentToDisplay= $link.length ?  $link.next().next('.news_content') : contentToDisplay;

}
contentToDisplay.show()
```

Comment: Checking shouldn't help at all. If `anchor[1]` is empty, jQuery will just match no elements (probably), and will continue processing things for 0 elements. Nothing will happen, but it won't fail. It would be different with vanilla Javascript, but jQuery is designed in a way that it wouldn't fail/matter with this case.

Comment: @Ian no, if selector returns no length, element doesn't exist. Is a common test for a jQuery selector. Without the check the first content was never being displayed and selector with no element match would just quit quietly

Comment: That's not my point, I'm not talking about `length`. I'm saying that if you try to select an element, or set of elements, and nothing matches (so the length is 0), but you still try to do stuff to it, jQuery won't bomb. For example, if you have `$("#fsafdasdfasdf").next()`, even though there is no element with the id "fsafdasdfasdf", the `next` call will simply return no elements. In vanilla Javascript, if you don't check beforehand, it will bomb. jQuery will continue processing, basically on nothing, but not fail.

Comment: @ian I just said exactly the same thing about the selector won't run any methods. Not sure what point is about native script, code is using jQUery so need to apply jQuery principles to test element